# object of type 'numpy.int64' has no len()

Tags: python, selenium

```
for i in dataframe.index:
    entry = dataframe.iloc[i]
    
    web.find_element(By.ID,'addNewRecordButton').click()

    firstname_input = web.find_element(By.ID,'firstName')
    firstname_input.send_keys(entry['Firstname'])

    lastname_input = web.find_element(By.ID,'lastName')
    lastname_input.send_keys(entry['Lastname'])

    email_input = web.find_element(By.ID,'userEmail')
    email_input.send_keys(entry['Email'])

    age_input = web.find_element(By.ID,'age')
    age_input.send_keys(entry['Age']) # this is where the problem starts

    salary_input = web.find_element(By.ID,'salary')
    salary_input.send_keys(entry['Salary']) # this is where the problem starts
    
    departemen_input = web.find_element(By.ID,'department')
    departemen_input.send_keys(entry['Departemen'])
```

i am on my way to make an automated data input using excel to a web form, but i am facing this problem. For the record, i am new in terms of python learning. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: That error means that you are calling the method `len` over some object of type `numpy.int64`, which is an integer and it has no `len` method. I guess that `entry['Age']` and `entry['Salary']` are the objects of type `numpy.int64` and that `send_keys` internally use the `len` method

Answer (score 1):

`send_keys` call internally to

```
def keys_to_typing(value):
    for val in value:
        ...
        elif isinstance(val, int):
            val = str(val)
            for i in range(len(val)):
                typing.append(val[i])
        else:
            for i in range(len(val)):
                typing.append(val[i])
```

It can handle `int`s, however `numpy.int64` is not "regular" Python `int` so the `else` block is executed. You need to cast it to an `int` or straight to `str` as the `keys_to_typing` function does

```
age_input.send_keys(str(entry['Age']))
```